# Why do I get quadrature points $\notin [0,\infty]$, when making own Gaussian quadrature rule with range $[0,\infty]$?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerics

For my project, I'm trying to calculate in *Mathematica* my own Gaussian quadrature rule (i.e. the quadrature points and weights) for a certain model with a parameter $x$ with the following (Maxwallian) probability density function: $\rho(x) = \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}\frac{1}{265^3} x^2 e^{-x^2 / (2\times 265^2)} $ on range $[0,\infty]$

Let ${P}(N)$ be the space with all polynomials of degree less or equal to $N$ and let $\{ \psi_n \}_{n=o}^{n=N} $ form an orthogonal basis with respect to our $\rho(x)$ on $[0,\infty]$. The $N$ Gaussian quadrature points are then defined as the roots of the $N$-th basis function, $\psi_N$. (Thus, to get the quadrature points one only has to determine the $N$-th orthogonal basis function and find the $N$ distinct roots.) This strategy seems to work for my other probability density functions in my project.

However, when I try to solve the quadrature points for this $\rho(x)$ I have the problem that when deriving more than $N>7$ quadrature points, the `NSolve` gives me negative and sometimes non-identical quadrature points as a solution, and I don't know why. I've tried a few things and think that or the Orthogonalization I do is wrong for basis functions of higher degree than 6, or maybe the way I use `NSolve` does not work in this case, or maybe something else? 
I would be happy with any suggestions to solve this.

Here is my *Mathematica* code:

```
Orthogonalbasis =  Orthogonalize[x^Range[0, 10],
   NIntegrate[#1*#2* Sqrt[(2/\[Pi])]*(1/(265^3)) *  x^2 * Exp[(-x^2/(2(265)^2))],
        {x, 0, Infinity}, MaxRecursion -> 16] &];
Quadraturepoints = x /. NSolve[Orthogonalbasis[[8]], x ]
```

> {-5723.14, 106.843, 264.616, 462.599, 692.796, 957.759, 1279.71}

(Where I have used the polynomial basis $\{1,x,...,x^{10} \}$, and used `MaxRecursion` to solve another problem).

But I don't understand why I get -5723.14 as quadrature point, which is not in $[0,\infty]$.  Even imaginary points occur when trying to solve the roots of higher degree basis functions, for instance solving the 8th and 9th degree polynomial basis function gives:

```
x /. NSolve[Orthogonalbasis[[9]], x]
```

> {-1439.52 - 770.095 I, -1439.52 + 770.095 I, 109.61, 269.795, 469.023, 699.113, 962.56, 1281.01}

```
x /. NSolve[Orthogonalbasis[[10]], x]
```

> {-1496.94 - 1528.1 I, -1496.94 + 1528.1 I, 107.32, 265.383, 463.198, 692.617, 956.015, 1275.05, 4776.29}

Any suggestions on how I can derive $N$ quadrature points in the range $[0,\infty]$?
Thank you!

NB: these are actually the half range generalized Hermite polynomials and points on $[0,\infty]$ :-)

Comment: Thanks David and @georhe2079 I'm quite new here :-)

Comment: I think its a precision problem. Have you tried `Integrate`? It should work in theory but make take a long time.  You might also work with higher working precision in `NIntegrate`

Comment: just tried it, `NIntegrate[ .. WorkingPrecision -> 100, MaxRecursion -> 50]` gives all real>0 roots.

Comment: @george2079, brilliant! That definitely solved the problem!
Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Integrate` to give a general, symbolic formula for the inner product and use `N[]` to speed up the orthogonalization.  One needs to use fairly high precision because the coefficients in the symbolic result become quite large in the OP's example.

```
(* OP's approach, with george2079's WorkingPrecision tip, for comparison *)
Orthogonalbasis = Orthogonalize[x^Range[0, 10], 
    NIntegrate[#1*#2*Sqrt[(2/π)]*(1/(265^3))*x^2*Exp[(-x^2/(2 (265)^2))],
      {x, 0, Infinity}, MaxRecursion -> 16, 
      PrecisionGoal -> 8, WorkingPrecision -> 32] &]; // AbsoluteTiming
Quadraturepoints =
   x /. NSolve[Orthogonalbasis[[8]], x, WorkingPrecision -> MachinePrecision]
(*
  {2.77581, Null}
  {87.3421, 219.779, 389.161, 587.07, 811.184, 1066.68, 1375.93}
*)

(* inner product *)
ClearAll[ip];
SetAttributes[ip, Listable];
ip[n_Integer, s_] =             (* basic integral, with parameter s *)
  Integrate[x^n*Sqrt[(2/π)]*(1/(s^3))*Exp[(-x^2/(2 (s)^2))],
   {x, 0, Infinity}, Assumptions -> n > 0 && n ∈ Integers && s > 0];
ip[f_, g_, s_] :=               (* inner product of f, g, with parameter s *)
  #.ip[Range[2, Length@# + 1], s] &@ CoefficientList[f*g, x]

(* orthogonalization, with s = 265, as in the OP *)
Orthogonalbasis = Orthogonalize[x^Range[0, 10], N[ip[##, 265], 100] &]; // AbsoluteTiming
Quadraturepoints2 =
   x /. NSolve[Orthogonalbasis[[8]], x, WorkingPrecision -> MachinePrecision]
(*
  {0.046954, Null}
  {87.3421, 219.779, 389.161, 587.07, 811.184, 1066.68, 1375.93}
*)
```

The `ip[]` method is about 65 times faster than the `NIntegrate[]` approach to orthogonalize the degree-10 basis.

---

**Addendum: *How `ip` computes the inner product***

There are two components, `ip[n, s]`, which represents the integral of the monomial `x^n` times the function `Sqrt[(2/π)]*(1/(s^3))*Exp[(-x^2/(2 (s)^2))]`, and `ip[f, g, s]`, which represents the inner product of polynomials `f` and `g` (assumed to depend on `x`). The inner product has a weight function ``Sqrt[(2/π)]*x^2*(1/(s^3))*Exp[(-x^2/(2 (s)^2))]`, which is`x^2`times the "reduced" weight function in`ip[n, s]`.

I defined `ip` to have the attribute `Listable` so that `ip[{2, 3, 4, 5}, s]` would return a list of the values of the integrals of `{x^2, x^3, x^4, x^5}`. These can be used to evaluate the integral of a polynomial by taking the dot product of these values with the coefficient list of the polynomial.

For instance for the inner product of a linear and quadratic polynomial, we would integrate

```
f*g   -> a0 + a1 x + a2 x^2 + a3 x^3
```

with respect to the inner product weight function, or equivalently the polynomial `f * g * x^2` with respect to the reduced weight function in `ip[n, s]`.  The degrees of the monomials are `{2, 3, 4, 5}`.  The coefficient list is given by

```
CoefficientList[f*g, x]   -> {a0, a1, a2, a3}
```

The list of degrees is given by

```
Range[2, Length@CoefficientList[f*g, x] + 1]   -> {2, 3, 4, 5}
```

Thus the inner product is given by

```
CoefficientList[f*g, x] . ip[Range[2, Length@CoefficientList[f*g, x] + 1], s]
```

which is coded more succinctly (and more efficiently) in the definition of `ip[f_, g_, s_]`.

Comment: Thank you for your helpful answer. 
However, I think I do not fully understand your code: 
When I try to use your method on finding the orthogonal system with respect to the weight function \rho(x) = x^(-2.3) on range [1,300], I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: I'm using your code, but now for x^(-2.3) instead of the maxwallian:

ip[n_Integer, s_] =(*I don't need to use s, so have set s=1 *)
  Integrate[x^n*(s^3 * x^(-2.3)), {x, 1, 300}, 
   Assumptions -> n > 0 && n \[Element] Integers && s > 0];
ip[f_, g_, s_] :=#.ip[Range[2, Length@# + 1], s] &@CoefficientList[f*g, x]

Orthogonalbasistest = 
 Orthogonalize[x^Range[0, 11], N[ip[##, 1], 1000] &]

But when I test it, I don;t get 0, e.g.:
Integrate[
 Orthogonalbasistest[[1]]*Orthogonalbasistest[[3]]*  x^(-2.3), {x, 1, 
  300}]  
(* 0.015378
*) 
Has this something to do with the s?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how to ask you this in a better way
Thanks in advance

Comment: Why are you multiplying the product of the basis elements by `x^2.3` instead of the weight function in the inner product? And why are you integrating only from `1` to `300`, instead of `0` to `Infinity`? (I don't see any relationship between your test integral and the inner product in your question. I'm not sure why the test integral ought to be zero.)

Comment: @AstroFloor I added some explanation. HTH

Comment: Thank you so much! Everything is crystal clear now! And such a nice way of orthogonalizing, brilliant! And I should have been more clear: the orthogonalisation of this system worked with your code. But I am also trying to find the orthogonal polynomials in case of other weight functions (and ranges). And I didn't understand your code properly and therefore got stuck. But it all works now, thank you so much! I'm really grateful!